# Symfony 5 convert xls to pdf PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, symfony

i looked through a lot of examples on the internet, but didn’t find one that worked,
found only how to convert html to pdf

I would like to find a quick solution - from Excel directly to PDF format

```
    <?php
     
    class PdfController extends AbstractController
    {
        public function getPdfFile($id)
        {
          // 
            $fileName = 'file.pdf';
            $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $fileName);
            $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    
            try {
                $writer->save($temp_file);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
            }

            //and here i want convert my xls file to pdf
        }
}
```

thank you for your answer

Comment: This should help. https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/#pdf

Comment: Please make sure to leave an answer as to how the problem was solved. Furthermore, the question itself misses any information on what you actually tried before resolving to asking a question on SO.